# Adding image to bottom of a svg circle

Tags: css, html, svg

This is my HTML:

```
<svg  viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" width="400" height="400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle  stroke="#efefef" stroke-width="2"
            cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" fill="url(#image1)"/>
    <g >
        <text  x="16.91549431" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="3">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</text>
        <text  x="16.91549431" y="17.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</text>
        <text  x="16.91549431" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.5">qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</text>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <pattern width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y="0" x="0" id="image1">
            <image xlink:href="http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-star-RTA9RqzTL.png" height="10" width="10" y="0" x="0"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

And I have got this [image]

> I need only one star beneath the qqqqqqqqqq text

Comment: The first step is to not use `<pattern>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<pattern>` element is for defining repeating fill patterns.  If you just want to place a single image, just use the `<image>` element.

```html
<svg  viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" width="400" height="400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle  stroke="#efefef" stroke-width="2"
            cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" fill="white"/>
    <g >
        <text  x="16.91549431" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="3">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</text>
        <text  x="16.91549431" y="17.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</text>
        <text  x="16.91549431" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.5">qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</text>
    </g>
   <image xlink:href="http://images.clipartpanda.com/clipart-star-RTA9RqzTL.png" height="10" width="10" y="21.5" x="11.9"></image>
</svg>
```